# Where should I put Velocity template files for a command line utility built with Maven?

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2, velocity

I have a small command line utility project that I'm using Maven to manage. The utility is a very simple app to populate a Velocity template and dump the results to a new file. My problem is where to put my Velocity templates. When I put them in `src/test/resources/foo/bar/baz`, `mvn test` fails because it can't find the referenced template, even though it is clearly there in `target/classes/foo/bar/baz`, which is where the `.class` file for the test and the class under test are located. If I put the template in the top-level directory of the project, the test passes, but then I'm not following the Maven project structure, and I suspect that the actual packaged .jar file wouldn't function. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

**Method under test**:

```
public final void mergeTemplate(final String templateFileName, final Writer writer) throws ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException, MethodInvocationException, IOException, Exception {
    Velocity.init();
    Velocity.mergeTemplate(templateFileName, Charset.defaultCharset().name(), context(), writer);
}
```

**Test method**:

```
@Test
public void testMergeTemplate() throws Exception {
    final FooGenerator generator = new FooGenerator();
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    generator.mergeTemplate("foo.yaml", writer);
    Assert.assertEquals("Something went horribly, horribly wrong.", EXPECTED_RESULT, writer.toString().trim());
}
```

The only place I can place `foo.yaml` and have the tests pass is in the root directory of the project, i.e., as a peer of `src` and `target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that instead of using something like

```
generator.mergeTemplate("foo.yaml", writer);
```

I should use something like

```
InputStream fooStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.yaml");
generator.mergeTemplate(fooStream, writer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically configure TEMPLATE_ROOT as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();        
props.put("file.resource.loader.path", templateRootDir);

VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.init(props);
engine.evaluate(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in src/main/resources/foo/bar/baz because they need to be included in the main jar file.

Comment: Fair enough. Now where do I put them to make my unit tests pass?

Comment: They should pass in src/main, but you're not describing the reason they're failing..? Is it a multi-module project ?

Comment: It's a very basic, single-module project. I'll update the question with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just configure Velocity to use the ClasspathResourceLoader, instead of the default FileResourceLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Velocity.setProperty() to set the properties similar to what was said above by @Jin Kim and was able to run it.

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(RunTimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER,"file");
ve.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path",templaterootdir);

ve.init();
```