# Unable to find resource while include another vm file into velocity template

Tags: java, include, velocity, template-engine

I have following code:

```
public class EmailService {
        static {
        Velocity.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
        Velocity.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class",
                "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        Velocity.init();

        try {
            InputStream in = EmailService.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("support.properties");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);
            SUPPORT_EMAIL = prop.getProperty("mail", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOException while reading support.properties");
        }
    }

    ....


    private String getResultString(VelocityContext context, Template velocityTemplate) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        velocityTemplate.merge(context, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

when executes line:

```
velocityTemplate.merge(context, writer);
```

I see the following error:

```
Method threw 'org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException' exception.
....
Unable to find resource 'footer.vm'
```

my template looks like this:

```
trololo
#include("footer.vm")
```

these two templates resides near on the filesystem.
[image]
How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this answer could help 
  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730335/how-to-include-a-file-from-a-velocity-template-using-classpathresourceloader

Comment: @cheb1k4 I have read this - doesn;t help

Answer (score 0):

working after replacing path

```
#include("velocityTemplates/footer.vm")
```